# In the Bohr model, is the 'energy efficiency' of absorption and emission of electromagnetic energy by the electrons 100%?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics

According to the Bohr model, the energy that the electrons absorb and emit during an excitation/de-excitation is expressed by the formula
$$
ΔE=E_{2}-E_{1}=hν,
$$
where $E_{1}$ is the energy of the electron before the absorption of the electromagnetic wave and $E_{2}$ is the energy of the electron after the absorption of it. The energies correspond to the discrete energy level for the corresponding orbit.

When the electron de-excites, is the total energy of the emitted electromagnetic waves equal to  the total energy absorbed, such that the 'energy efficiency' is 100%?

Comment: There are no elecromagnetic waves, even in the Bohr model. **The atom**  is excited by a single photon and de-xcites by a single photon. One four vector of energy-momentum takes part. Accumulation of photons by many atoms may show a width in the frequency of the collection seen as light. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/atspect.html